# Can someone please explain why the method-methodOfTest() is skipped after executing the initialization block?

Tags: java

```
public class UnaryOp {
    static int i=1;

    static{
        i= i-- + --i;
        System.out.println(i); // Result comes 0
    }

    {
        i=i++ - ++i;
        System.out.println("i valus is" +i); //Result comes -2
    }

    int methodOfTest(){
        return i+i - i*i/i;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("new UnaryOp().methodOfTest()); //How the result comes as i=-2 when executed instead i=1?


    }

}
```

Execution flow is:

- Static block
- initialization block
- then methodfOfTest().

When memory allocation happens then initialization block is executed and i value is -2. But according to me, when methodfOfTest() is executed then the i value should be 1. But its showing -2 that is the i value of initialization block.

Can anyone explain me how?

Comment: Operator precedence? `i+i - i*i/i;` is `i` Why are you expecting 1?

Comment: @usr7587773 It would be a good idea to learn how to debug your program. Start by putting some `println` statements to see how `i` is changing in your code. Let the program explain to you what is happening.

Comment: Reason code is not executing: *It doesn't compile!!*

Comment: 'According to me, ... the `i` value should be 1'. **Why?**

Comment: Thank you , I got my mistake. I was not assuming the continuity between initialization block and methodfOfTest(). And that's how i was getting i=1 as answer. which is incorrect.

Comment: Both the static initalizer and the instance initializer are irrelevant. You agree that after both the value of `i` is -2. The only issue here appears to be your incorrect expectation of the result of `methodOfTest()`.

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all there is error in this code on

   System.out.println("new UnaryOp().methodOfTest()); //How the result comes     as i=-2 when executed instead i=1?

as you have added unnecessary quote

2. YES  Execution flow is correct.

   static block

   initialization block

   methodfOfTest().

when methodOfTest() is executing the value of i is   -2

Then the operator precedence is:

1. *
2. /
3. +
4. -

so the result will be evalutaed as   (-2*-2)=4  and now 4/-2=-2

now -2+-2=-4
The expression becomes

```
-4-(-2)=-2
```

This expression is evaluated according to operator precedence.